# How to get average between first row and current row per each group in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

i have data frame like this,

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| a | 4 |
| a | 3 |
| a | 5 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |
| c | nan |
| c | 5 |

the resulted data frame contain new column ['average'] and to get its values will be:

- make group-by(id)
- first row  in 'average' column per each group is equal to its corresponding value in 'value'
- other rows in ' average' in group  is equal to mean for all previous rows in 'value'(except current value)

the resulted data frame must be :

| id | value | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 2 |
| a | 4 | 2 |
| a | 3 | 3 |
| a | 5 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 1 |
| b | 4 | 1 |
| b | 3 | 2.5 |
| c | 1 | 1 |
| c | nan | 1 |
| c | 5 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the dataframe by `id`, then calculate the expanding mean for `value` column for each groups, then shift the expanding mean and get it back to the original dataframe, once you have it, you just need to `ffill` on `axis=1` on for the `value` and `average` columns to get the first value for the categories:

```py
out = (df
       .assign(average=df
               .groupby(['id'])['value']
               .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift(1))
               )
       )
out[['value', 'average']] = out[['value', 'average']].ffill(axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  id  value  average
0  a    2.0      2.0
1  a    4.0      2.0
2  a    3.0      3.0
3  a    5.0      3.0
4  b    1.0      1.0
5  b    4.0      1.0
6  b    3.0      2.5
7  c    1.0      1.0
8  c    NaN      1.0
9  c    5.0      1.0
```

Comment: Nice answer, voting above mine. I didn't know about the Pandas 'expanding': https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html

Comment: @iimm great that it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which, I think, satisfies the requirements. Here, the first row in a group of `id`s is simply passing its value to the `average` column. For every other row, we take the average where the index is smaller than the current index.

You may want to specify how you want to handle the NaN values. In the below, I set them to `None` so that they are ignored.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import average
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 2],
    ['a', 4],
    ['a', 3],
    ['a', 5],
    ['b', 1],
    ['b', 4],
    ['b', 3],
    ['c', 1],
    ['c', np.NAN],
    ['c', 5]
], columns=['id', 'value'])

# Replace the NaN value with None
df['value'] = df['value'].replace(np.nan, None)

id_groups = df.groupby(['id'])

id_level_frames = []

for group, frame in id_groups:
    print(group)

    # Resets the index for each id-level frame
    frame = frame.reset_index()

    for index, row in frame.iterrows():
        # If this is the first row:
        if index== 0:
            frame.at[index, 'average'] = row['value']

        else:
            current_index = index
            earlier_rows = frame[frame.index < index]
            frame.at[index, 'average'] = average(earlier_rows['value'])

    id_level_frames.append(frame)

    final_df = pd.concat(id_level_frames)
```